# MySQL: How do you update a field on duplicate key for a value other than 1?

Tags: mysql, variables, duplicates, increment, calculated-columns

I've seen the question regarding how to increment a column value when a duplicate insert is attempted:

```
insert into table (col) values (val) on duplicate update countcol=countcol+1;
```

But how do you increment the countcol by a variable value?

For example:

```
insert into table (col, count) values (val1, val2) on duplicate update count=count+val2?
```

Suppose I'm tracking the number of books read by students and my table contains:

```
Mark | 5
```

Mark reports reading 2 more books, so I want:

`Mark | 7` (add 2 to existing total)

But I want to handle the case where Jerry (new to the program) reads 2 books

insert--> `Jerry | 2`

Maybe something like;

```
insert into readers (student, count)values ('Mark',3 as read) 
on duplicate key update count=count+read;
```

Are there actual names/references I can access for the values submitted in mySQL?  Can this be done in a single statement?  Or do I need to first test to see if the record exists and then insert/update depending on the result?

Comment: `on duplicate key` only works with primary or unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `values()`:

```
insert into table (col, count)
    values (val1, val2)
    on duplicate update count = count + values(count);
```

`values()` refers to the value being passed into the `insert`.